# Evil mode hook with specific major mode?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

Is it possible to hook `evil-insert-enter-state` and other states only within org-mode with the `org-toggle-latex-fragment`?

p.s.

finally the suggestions work. I currently have the following pieces that make the org mode automatically render the content when you are in the normal mode, but expand the content when you are in other modes.

```
(defun org-preview-all-latex-fragments ()
  "Toggle all the latex fragments."
     (org-toggle-latex-fragment '(16)))


(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (add-hook 'evil-normal-state-entry-hook 'org-preview-all-latex-fragments nil t)
                           (add-hook 'evil-normal-state-exit-hook 'org-remove-latex-fragment-image-overlays nil t)))
```

Comment: I think something like `(when (eq major-mode 'org-mode) ...` in a 'global' `evil-insert-enter-state` hook is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add buffer local hooks inside a org-mode hook:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook 'org-toggle-latex-fragment nil t)))
```

The third argument of `add-hook` is the buffer-local flag.

```
(add-hook HOOK FUNCTION &optional APPEND LOCAL)
```

The problem with the above is that `org-toggle-latex-fragment` works differently depending on where the cursor is. If you mean to activate all latex fragments across the file, you may need to modify my suggestion slighty:

```
(defun org-toggle-all-latex-fragments ()
  (org-toggle-latex-fragment '(16)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook 'org-toggle-all-latex-fragments nil t)))
```

Comment: what does '(16) mean?

Comment: `org-toggle-latex-fragment`'s first argument is called the universal argument. '(16) forces `org-toggle-latex-fragment` to toggle all latex previews in the current file.

Comment: Should also mention: passing '(16) to it is the equivalent of typing `C-u C-u M-x org-toggle-latex-fragment`

Comment: I made it work. It is now great. Just one more comment. I am not sure why org-preview-latex-fragment is deprecated. Should it be normal that people want to control explicitly if they want to switch the image overlay on or off?